# To pass on the data from Multiple data sources to a common function

Tags: php, mysql

I am designing a website using PHP and MySQL. For a webpage i am fetching data from multiple sources. Now, i am passing on the data to a function which is common for many webpages. The function using the data queries the database again and produces the obtained result. The problem is, the common function does not refer to any database implicitly. Since, the data i pass would be from one of the two databases, the function just looks for the data in one of the database and is returning null in case its not available. Now, if i modify the function to search in two databases there are other pages which will be impacted.I would like to know if there are any workarounds for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can [`UNION` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) across two databases for example:

```
SELECT id, title FROM database_one.table_name WHERE id = $id
UNION
SELECT id, title FROM database_two.table_name WHERE id = $id
```

This will give you the results of both SQL statements in one query. In this way you will get all records that match your criteria from both tables in both databases.

`UNION` requires that both statements return the same number of columns so that is why I have specified them instead of using the `*` wildcard.

If you want to ensure you only get unique records back (the same record could appear in both databases) then you can make use of the `DISTINCT` modifier.